# Why do I need an extra escape in this vim errorformat?

Tags: vim

I'm writing a compiler script for python. I have this errorformat that correctly parses Tracebacks:

```
CompilerSet errorformat=
          \%A\ \ File\ \"%f\"\\,\ line\ %l%.%#,
          \%Z\ \ \ \ %m
```

I don't understand why I need the extra escape before the comma: why can't `\"%f\"\\,` be `\"%f\"\,`? I understand that the comma needs to be escaped because it's used to delimit sections of the errorformat, but why two backslashes?

Here's an example of a Traceback where the single escape doesn't work, but the double does:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    g()
File "test.py", line 7, in g
    f()
File "test.py", line 4, in f
    raise IndexError()
IndexError
```

Another similar example is [this python compiler script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=477) that uses three backslashes!

(I ask in the hopes that understanding why will make it easier to write more `efm` settings.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `:help efm-entries`:

> To include a comma in a pattern precede it with a backslash (you have to type
>   two in a ":set" command).  To include a backslash itself give two backslashes
>   (you have to type four in a ":set" command).  You also need to put a backslash
>   before a space for ":set".

Inside `'errorformat'`, a comma is special, namely an entry separator. To match a literal comma, you have to escape it (once): `\,`. Okay, but in `:set` there's another round of escaping (e.g. to deal with spaces in the value), so the `\` gets escaped another time: `\\,`. Often, you can avoid that second round of escaping by using `:let` (but not in the `:CompilerSet` command here).